# Will I lose any of my Android studio stuff when upgrading to Windows 10?

Tags: windows, android-studio, sdk

So Microsoft is giving Windows user a chance to upgrade to Windows 10 for free!

But will I lose any of my Android Studio projects?

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't lose your projects, you'll just lose the ability to run them on the [Intel haxm accelerator](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager). So if you only use real Android devices to test your applications on, this shouldn't be an issue.

Windows 10 is supposed to support the Intel emulator for Android, but the last I checked that wasn't working yet. There are other fast third party emulators for Android, but I do not know if they work on Windows 10 yet. For all I know, they might be.

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't lose any of your projects.